# ViewPager + Fragments + Navigation Drawer and switching fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, navigation-drawer

My app consists of MainActivity which hosts `NavigationDrawer`. The left drawer contains ListView with menu items. Clicking an item in the list menu switches a `Fragment` on the content_frame. The initial content of the drawer is a `ViewPager` which creates Fragments via FragmentPagerAdapter. Rest of menu items forces creation of a single Fragment via transaction. 
The problem is that all of the fragments populates items to menu. Sometimes, the menu items are displayed several times (the come from only 1 fragment type). 
How to assure that the Fragment that is being replaced correctly removes its menu items from ActionBar and the newly created Fragment correctly adds items to ActionBar?

[image]

See my layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" -->
<!-- android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" -->
<!-- android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" -->
<!-- android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDrawerMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="pl.cubesoft.photoviewer.fragment.DrawerMenuFragment" />

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Code that switches Fragments:

```
    private boolean selectMenuOption(int position) {
    boolean result = false;

    switch (position) {
    case 0: {
        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, MainPagerFragment.newInstance());
        ft.commit();



        result = true;
        break;
    }
    case 1:{

        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, UploadMediaListFragment.newInstance());
        ft.commit();

        /*mUploadMediaListFragment.initialize(getPhotoViewerApplication().getUploadManager(), 
                getPhotoViewerApplication().getImageLoader());
        */


        result = true;
        break;
        }

    case 2: {

        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, LocalMediaGridFragment.newInstance());
        ft.commit();


        result = true;
        break;

    }

    case 3: {

        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, AppPreferencesFragment.newInstance(R.xml.main_preferences));
        ft.commit();


        result = true;
        break;

    }

    }

    if (result && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mLeftDrawer)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawer);
    } 
    return false;
}
```

MainPagerFragment contains ViewPager. Its children are fragments populated from FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment result = null;
    if ( mProvider == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    switch (mProvider.getViewType(mUserId, position)) {
    case PHOTO_GROUP_STREAM: {
        final PhotoGroupsGridFragment fragment = PhotoGroupsGridFragment.newInstance(mUserId);
        //final PhotoGroupsProvider photoGroupProvider = mProvider.getPhotoGroupsProvider(mUserId);
        //fragment.initialize(photoGroupProvider, mImageLoader, mUserId);

        result = fragment;
        break;
    }
    case PHOTO_STREAM: {
        final PhotoGroupGridFragment fragment = PhotoGroupGridFragment.newInstance(mUserId, GroupType.FAVOURITE_GROUP, 0);
        //fragment.initialize(mProvider.getPhotoGroupProvider(mUserId, GroupType.FAVOURITE_GROUP, 0), mImageLoader);

        result = fragment;
        break;
    }

    case PHOTO_RECENT_STREAM: {
        final PhotoGroupGridFragment fragment = PhotoGroupGridFragment.newInstance(mUserId, GroupType.RECENT_GROUP, 0);
        //fragment.initialize(mProvider.getPhotoGroupProvider(mUserId, GroupType.RECENT_GROUP, 0), mImageLoader);
        /*fragment.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                //ActivityHelper.showPhotoGroupActivity( mContext, position );
            }
        });*/
        result = fragment;
        break;
    }

    case PHOTO_USER_STREAM: {
        final PhotoGroupGridFragment fragment = PhotoGroupGridFragment.newInstance(mUserId, GroupType.STREAM_GROUP, 0);
        //fragment.initialize(mProvider.getPhotoGroupProvider(mUserId, GroupType.STREAM_GROUP, 0), mImageLoader);
        /*fragment.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                //ActivityHelper.showPhotoGroupActivity( mContext, position );
            }
        });*/
        result = fragment;
        break;
    }

    case USER_LIST: {
        final UserListFragment fragment = UserListFragment.newInstance(UserListType.FRIENDS_LIST);

        result = fragment;
        break;
    }

    case CONTACT_LIST: {
        final UserListFragment fragment = UserListFragment.newInstance(UserListType.CONTACTS_LIST);

        result = fragment;
        break;
    }

    case PHOTO_FEATURED_STREAM: {
        final PhotoGroupGridFragment fragment = PhotoGroupGridFragment.newInstance(mUserId, GroupType.FEATURED_GROUP, 0);
        result = fragment;
        break;
    }

    case COMMENT_STREAM: {
        final PhotoCommentsFragment fragment = PhotoCommentsFragment.newInstance(mUserId, null, null);

        result = fragment;
        break;
    }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It can be an indication that you have orphan frames. You should possibly dump existing frames and deduce how the lost frames emerges. First suspicion - try to remove the static frame reference from the xml-layout and replace it with dynamic creation by Java inside a contaioner.

Comment: Adding related Java code could be helpful.

Comment: I edited my question and added code which causes problems.

Comment: Do the duplicated menu items come from ViewPager's fragments, or from top-level fragments in content_frame? If you use `getSupportFragmentManager` for your `ViewPager` try using `getChildFragmentManager` instead (because ViewPager's fragments are children of the MainPagerFragment, if I got it correctly). Just a guess.

Comment: If this doesn't help, again try to dump fragments (`getSupportFragmentManager().dump("", null, new PrintWriter(System.out, true), null);`) or `enableDebugLogging`. I'm sure that only orphan fragment can cause duplicated menu items. BTW, did you analyse, what happens if a user clicks the same position twice?

Comment: Maybe this bug? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61438&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars